# What is "this" in c# and how can a static field be "null"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning game development in Unity 4.6.9. When I added background music to my game it was stacking every time I clicked ***play again*** button. So, I searched and found that I have to destroy extra music objects creating every time I clicked play again, so I used following code:-

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class MusicPlayer : MonoBehaviour {
static MusicPlayer instance=null;//DOUT

void Start () {
    if (instance != null) {
        Destroy (gameObject);
        print ("Duplicate music-player self destructing");
    } else {
        instance=this;//DOUT
        GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
    }
}
}
```

**1.** I am unable to understand line 5 & 12. In line 5 we are creating instance variable, which is static & has value equal to null of type **MusicPlayer** but in c# there is no such kind of data type. In line 12 what is the meaning of ***this***?

**2.** Also, I know Static objects get created once. Because of that, when we start the game this object is forever un-destroyable. But can’t we make a normal integer variable count and setting its value to 0, like this:

```cs
int count = 0;
void Start () {
    if (count > 0) {
        Destroy(gameObject);
        print (“delete duplicate music player”);
    } else {
        count++;
        GameObject.DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: The phrase "my game it was stacking" is not clear. In English, to "stack" means to put one thing on top of another, but I wonder if you meant "my game was getting stuck" i.e. crashing or hanging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static variables not only just get created once, they are are also shared among all instances of the class.  Your integer variable increment approach will work fine IF you make it a static variable, so that the new `MusicPlayer` instance will see the value that has been updated by the previously created `MusicPlayer`.

Both your approach using an integer variable and the example using a `MusicPlayer` variable achieve the same thing.  The first `MusicPlayer` instance to be created sets some static state that will be visible to any instances created later on, letting them know that a valid `MusicPlayer` instance has already been instantiated.

That being said, I personally think that using a MusicPlayer variable initially set to null is a better representation of the algorithm.

For your question regarding `this`, it refers to this instance of the class.

And `MusicPlayer` is the name of the class, so it is just a reference to a class instance.

So you create `instance` to hold a pointer to an instance of `MusicPlayer`.  You initialize it to `null`.  Then when the first class instance is created, you set `instance` to point to the new class instance that was just created using `this`.  Future instances of `MusicPlayer` will see that `instance` is not `null` and will destroy themselves.

Of course, this class currently does nothing, you still need to add an Audio Source or something to it to implement playing music.

Comment: Your first sentence starts off wrong, it is possible to create static variable more than once. For example, across app domains.

Comment: Is `instance` is the name of the object for class `MusicPlayer` initialized to `null`?

Comment: Yes, like in your first code example in your question

Comment: ok, so I know that `this` is a reference variable that refers to the current object. So, by putting `instance=this;` in else loop we are trying to tell compiler that object has been created, right? Please explain if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, that is basically correct....though it happens at runtime, so we are not telling the compiler...we are telling any MusicPlayer objects that get created after the first one.

Answer (score 0):

1a. You (or somebody else) created the Type MusicPlayer by inheriting from MonoBehavior. Therefore it is now a type that can be used for variables. **Inlcuding** variables in the class itself (most languages support this or soemthing like that).

1b. This is a way to access a Instance from within a Instance Function. It is mostly used to resolve any ambiguity between Class Fields/properties and Arguments. But it can be used to get a reference to make furtehr calls on

2.Actually this class has to be instantiated. There is no permanently existing instance. Unless I am missing something, the automatic public and parameterless Constructor will still exist.

There is a static variable that you assign a instance too (and keep it assigned too). And the static variable happens to be in the class itself. But that is it.

This whole approach can work to make certain there "can be only one" Music player to some degree. Of course a simple approach would be to just stop the current playback of the MediaPlayer and start a new track instead. The SingletonPattern can be used to make certain that there is only one instance, but for Sound playing usually multiple instances are wanted (old games had limits like 16-32 channels, but this time is long passed).

Answer (score 0):

Class itself is definition of new data type. When you create a new game object with MusicPlayer script new MusicPlayer object is created, and it's Start() method is run.  This keyword is replaced with a referance to current object (this on Start() method is called), so it's just saving an object of type MusicPlayer to static varieable . And yea replacing referance which a single primitive data like bool or int would me memory saver, but make sure you will not have to run any methods on this MusicPlayer (like pause or something), because only way to do it is by keeping this referance, if you lose it you lose control over this object. It's also not true that objects are kept forever there is a thing called garbage collector, that clears memory durning program runtime, and if it will think object is no more needed it will be erased.